# What preprocessing steps to be followed before image comparison?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, image-classification

1
down vote
favorite

For example I am trying to find the similarity between two images using skimage - SSIM. The code block will be as follows

```
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim as ssim
from skimage import io
from skimage.transform import resize

a = io.imread("http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51PV4Dd8wAL._AC_UL246_SR190,246_.jpg",as_grey=False,dtype="float64")
b = io.imread("http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/914ZHE6JolL._UY500_.jpg",as_grey=False,dtype="float64")

a = resize(a,b.shape)
ssim(a, b,multichannel=True)
```

I got the similarity score as follows

```
0.21009350738786017
```

Although both the images are same where one images in slightly oriented , I am getting very really low scores for this comparisons. Am I missing any preprocessing steps here before I compute compare images. If so what are the things I should consider before comparing images.

Thanks In Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

There is not any fault! This is one of pitfalls of SSIM. It is very sensitive to the geometrical degradations such as orientation!